# Are we allowed to post questions that allow you to do something that may be against the Terms and Conditions of another software?

Tags: discussion

I've developed a batch file that automates the steps a human would have to take to install the bypasser for a certain software protection.

The batch file only checks where to put the files and does the copying: it does not do anything else.
If any other files were added to the folder, it would be doing the same exact copying, except for a specific file.

Such operation may be against the Terms and Conditions.

---

In this case, the software is a game called Blade and Soul, having the code (for now) hosted on https://www.bnsbuddy.com/index.php?threads/xigncode-bypasser-installer.390/

The code applies the XignCode Bypasser on the game, where the files are hosted somewhere else.

---

With this being said, is this off-topic for review?

Comment: why can't you use a working example where Terms and Conditions are not potentially going to be violated?

Comment: I believe I can't do that because the batch reads a value in a specific registry key and stores the files inside the folder stored in that same key. I could, however, create a different registry key and let it do the copying. If the registry keys are present but the directories don't have the game there (but the tree exists), then it would be okay. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Slightly related: [question about malicious code](/q/1517/9357)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think it's off-topic as at the end of the day we're just reviewing code.

It may be a moral grey area, but it can be argued that any language, framework or program can be used for 'bad'. It just depends on how you use it. And so you can redact or abstract your data so that it just looks like normal every day data with normal code.

Comment: ...or you can say it's just for educational purposes.

Comment: As indicated by the link provided by 200_success, we don't really have a problem with malicious software. We've allowed keyloggers and monitoring software in the past. **It doesn't need to be abstracted**, we never outlawed it. Users may disagree and downvote anyway, but such code is not against the rules of this Stack Exchange.

Comment: @t3chb0t That has never fooled anyone.

Comment: Since the majority upvoted this answer (13 up/1 down), I decided to post my question in the next days. Thank you for your answer.